# 7-Zip: Empty tar file created

Tags: windows-7, tar, 7-zip, portable-apps

Using [7-Zip portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) i created a tar file containing a folder which also contains numerous files and folders (200mb+).

When i open the tar file it is empty, but the size of the tar file is exactly the same as the size of the folder which it supposedly contains.

*It might be worth noting that the tar was outputted to a USB drive, and that the program also runs from the same USB drive. Also it has worked in the past using the same version.*

Why does this happen and how can i fix it?

Does 7-Zip require any specific dependencies that may be missing causing this to happen?

Comment: Was this done using the GUI or command line?  If you're using the GUI, determine the results when you try the command line, because that can be easier for others to replicate issues.  What are the results of "7za l filename.tar" or "7za t filename.tar"?  What happens if you try to add one more file to the tar file?  Please provide precise command lines that you've used/tried.  As far as I know, 7-zip doesn't have any dependencies for tar.  (Some releases (for some operating systems) might for the RAR format.)

Comment: This was done using the GUI, the portable application works fine on my home computer. But when operating it on a restricted network computer at my academic institution it doesn't work as intended. I cant use the CLI because they are restricted network computers. The funny thing is that when i use a different format such as 7z it works as expected.

Comment: I cant help but think this may be a dependency issue for tar.

Comment: Sounds more like file associations are running 7-Zip for *.7z files, and something else for *.tar files.  From the 7-Zip file manager (which, it sounds like, you can access by opening a 7z file), choose to Open a different file, and try opening the tar.  If that works, then the problem was that you weren't using the same 7-Zip when the problems were being experienced.  If that doesn't work, I have doubts that you'll get a better answer without more details.